# trouble adding bridges

Tags: bridge, mac

I'm trying to add bridges to Tor but it has now been two hours and I'm still getting the "loading relay information" message;  is this normal? ; I'm currently running 143 Mbps

Comment: Tor or Tor Browser? Which OS? How did you add the bridge? Did you change your config file and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure your time and timezone are accurate. Tor may face issues if the time is off. Then restart the browser.

If the above doesn't work, it may be that the bridge is being blocked. You may want to try [pluggable transports](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/circumvention/).